# Is there an ambient light cheat/command in “Don’t Starve”?

Tags: cheats, dont-starve

Is there a console command or cheat code or something in *Don’t Starve* that will make it bright like daytime?

I checked the [console command list](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Console), but there was nothing. I’ve seen some mods that can make it perpetually daytime, but that has no effect in caves.

Is there a way to set the ambient light to full visibility, even underground?

Comment: I'd recommend focusing more on the *problem at hand*: Ambient darkness in caves, rather than presuming a solution already. :)

Comment: Same question, different words.

Comment: Try playing as Willow?

Comment: @Kyralessa, even the Star Caller’s Staff is no good, lighting up only a relatively small area. Willow isn’t much better. The goal is to simulate day time (or a really large forest fire).

Comment: At the moment nobody knows of a way to do this, but that's more through lack of trying than anything else. There's probably a mod for it, I had a look but couldn't find one.